# Windows 2008 R2 ftpes, can't upload files

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ftp, upload, ftps

I've setup an ftpes server (ftp with explicit TLS) on a Windows 2008 R2 Server. I am able to connect but when an upload is finished the file is deleted on the Server and I get this error (with filezilla):

Antwort:    550 
Fehler: Dateiübertragung fehlgeschlagen (Error: File transfer failed)

The strange thing is that if connected to the same Server with the same user without Encryption (plain ftp) - everything works.

When I watch the Directory with sysinternal filemonitor i can see that svchost.exe is deleting the file.

Also tried passive and active Transmission. Different FTP Clients. Windows 2012 Server.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: FileZilla log? (really the log, not the list of message from GUI). What FTP server? IIS?

Answer (score 0):

FYI

Installing this hotfix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2888853 helped.

Lothar